# EXTjs fieldcontainer focus event not firing

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to get this to work in [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com)

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'FieldContainer Example',
            width: 550,
            bodyPadding: 10,


            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                fieldLabel: 'Last Three Jobs',
                labelWidth: 100,
                listeners: {
                    focus: function(fld, e, opts) {
                        alert("onFocus");
                    }
                },

                // The body area will contain three text fields, arranged
                // horizontally, separated by draggable splitters.
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to attach the focus listener on the text field and not to the field container as it does not get the focus.

```
items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        focus( a, event, eOpts ){
                            alert("onFocus");
                        }
                    },
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }]
```

working code [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10c0)

Hope this helps!